# Converting a CSV file for Hydrologic Model

Tags: python, csv, text-files

I'm working with a utility within the calibration software PEST that is only compatible with a Sample Site File type. I would like to use this utility to calibrate my model, but my model's output is in a very different format (CSV). SSF is tab delimited and only contains 4 key columns of data: Sample Site ID, Date (MM/DD/YYYY), Time, and Streamflow.

Example of SSF file:

```
134 01/01/1980 00:00:00 34
134 01/02/1980 00:00:00 30
134 01/03/1980 00:00:00 28
134 01/04/1980 00:00:00 38
```

The output from my hydrologic model is written to CSV files that contain the Date (YYYYMMDD), Simulated Flow (Qsim), Observed Flow (Qobs), Temperature, Precipitation, Actual Evaporation, Potential Evaporation, and Snow-Water Equivalent.

Example of model output:

```
134
Date, Qsim, Qobs, Temp, Precip, AET, PET, SWE
19800101, 34, 31, 11, 21, 3.4, 4.0, 0
19800102, 30, 30, 11, 15, 3.0, 4.4, 0
19800103, 28, 25, 12, 0, 3.1, 4.0, 0
19800104, 38, 45, 8, 30, 0.5, 3.8, 0
```

So I've determined that in order to make the conversion I will to:

1. add a column 0 that contains the site ID (row 0 in csv file)
2. delete rows 0 and 1 in the csv file
3. delete rows 2-7 in the csv file
4. add a column for the time (in this case, I just need "00:00:00" in the col 2 for each row)
5. reformat the dates from YYYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY
6. write the file tab delimited

I am definitely a beginner with python, and this is the code I've been able to write so far:

```
import csv
HBVout = csv.reader(open('C:\\ENVpest\\Output\\Results.csv', 'rb'))
HBVout.next()
newSSF = csv.writer(open('SSF1.txt', 'wb+'), delimiter='\t')

for cline in HBVout:
    new_line = [val for col, val in enumerate(cline) if col not in (2,3,4,5,6,7)]
    newSSF.writerow(new_line)
```

I'm able to skip the first row, delete the unnecessary columns, and rewrite as a tab delimited file. I would greatly appreciate any help with adding columns to a file and with reformating the dates! I've scoured the other questions on SO and other sites, but haven't found any luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Your code was a little confusing at first because it's reading the output of another program which you're calling `HBVout`. I also didn't understand what you meant in #3 about deleting rows 2-7 in the csv file so have ignored it. Although the `datetime` module could have been used to convert the format of the date, it was so trivial, it's just done manually.

One notable difference is the data is read in using a `csv.DictReader` because that make accessing the various field more readable since each line read becomes a dictionary of values.

```
import csv

with open('Results.csv', 'rb') as inf, open('SSF1.txt', 'wb') as outf:
    site_id = inf.next().rstrip()  # read past site id on first line
    HBVout = csv.DictReader(inf, skipinitialspace=True)  # will read header line
    ssf = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t')

    for data in HBVout:
        date = data['Date']  # convert date from YYYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY 
        date = '/'.join((date[4:6], date[6:8], date[0:4]))
        ssf.writerow([site_id, date, '00:00:00', data['Qsim']])
```

Contents of SSF file created from model output example:

```
134\t01/01/1980\t00:00:00\t34\n
134\t01/02/1980\t00:00:00\t30\n
134\t01/03/1980\t00:00:00\t28\n
134\t01/04/1980\t00:00:00\t38\n
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the "delete rows 2-7" was a typo, was meant to be "delete columns 2-7." 

I am getting a syntax error when I run the code though, regarding the comma between "open() as inf, open () as outf" and I'm not sure why that's a syntax error. Do you have any ideas on what might fix it?

Other than that, I REALLY love the script you've written for this, it's super simple and accomplishes everything in a very straightfoward way. I definitely need to look into DictReader more, it seems like a pretty powerful way to reorganize CSV files.

Comment: Multiple context expressions like that shown weren't allowed until Python 2.7. The workaround is to just nest one inside the other which will make it necessary to also indent all the statements inside the two another level as well.

Comment: Yes, works with nested "work... as" statements, but I'm now receiving a "KeyError: Date." Having little experience with DictReader(), I've just started looking into it a little, but haven't found a clear solution to this Key error yet. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Well, keys are case-sensitive and have to match what's on the `Date, Qsim, Qobs, Temp, Precip, AET, PET, SWE` header line in your model's output file. It's also important to include the `skipinitialspace=True` option when creating the `DictReader` instance to make sure leading whitespace isn't being included as part of each key. You can always `print data` at the top of the `for` loop and see exactly what the keys are in the dictionary being created from each line read from the input file.

Comment: Ah I see. The `print data` worked well to understand what's going on. I also did a `print site_ID`. It appears to be skipping the first line entirely. The line 'Date, Qsim, Qobs...' is being assigned to site ID and the first row of data is being assigned as the keys. Sorry to keep bothering you about this, but would you know what in the code might be causing this? My first instinct was to play around with the `site_ID = ...` line but just removing the `next()` definitely isn't working.

Comment: The best I can do is describe what the code is supposed to do (and did when tested with the example data in your question). The initial `inf.next()` call is to read in the site id line and advance the file position to the header line, so that will become the first line that `csv.DictReader()` sees and be recognized as field names and be used as keys in the dictionaries which will be created for each line read after that. It's necessary because your model output file isn't quite a proper csv file since it's got that extra site id line at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting the dates can quite easily be done using the builtin `datetime` module, something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime("19800508", "%Y%m%d")  # convert your string to a 
                                             # datetime object
s = d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")  # gives the string "08/05/1980"
```

Admittedly this module is a bit confusing to use - I always have to look up the documentation before using it - but it is pretty powerful. Dealing with date conversions is not something one wants to have to do manually.

I don't have much experience with the `csv` module but I think you're on the right track.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was looking into `datetime` a bit, but it was definitely a bit confusing to work out on my own!